# Display woocommerce notice through Ajax callback on product page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to display a woocommerce notice in a product page. The notice should by displayed by an ajax callback function, triggered by a button.

The callback is working correctly, but no notice is being displayed.

Here is my code:

**jQuery/AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            
    $('#return-button').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'my_custom_function',
                product_id: id
            },
            success: function(response) { 
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP Callback**

```
function my_custom_function() {
    error_log('Function called');

    wc_add_notice("Success!", "notice");
    wc_print_notices();

    wp_die();
}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

`wc_print_notices()` default effect is to echo the HTML code of the notices. The content echoed by `my_custom_function` corresponds to the `response` param in the AJAX success function. So it just has to be displayed/inserted in the DOM.

Note: wc_print_notices() can also return the value instead of echoing. This can be done by setting the `$return` param as `true` [1](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_print_notices/).

Here is the working code:

**jQuery/AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            
    $('#return-button').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'my_custom_function',
                product_id: id
            },
            success: function(response) { 
                $('woocommerce-notices-wrapper').append(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP Callback:**

```
function my_custom_function() {
    error_log('Function called');

    wc_add_notice("Success!", "notice");
    wc_print_notices();
        
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: it's Monday morning and I may not be fully awake yet, but it looks like you're forgetting the true parameter for wc_print_notices in your php callback.