# Woocommerce - Display notice with ajax form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, woocommerce

I'm editing the woocommerce form-edit-account.php template. The template contains a form that allows users to change the settings (name, surname, etc.). Originally the form does not perform ajax requests, so to save the settings without refreshing the page I added ajax requests. Everything works fine except handling error. When a field is left blank or not respected in its conditions, woocommerce error messages do not appear.

I found a similar post here, but couldn't figure out how to fit it according to my form.: [Display woocommerce notice through Ajax callback on product page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72383088/display-woocommerce-notice-through-ajax-callback-on-product-page)

My problem is that the form continues to work normally, when the fields are not respected I do not see any error message after submitting. However when the page is reloaded the messages are displayed correctly. So I'm getting the messages inserted in functions.php but only after page refresh and not at submit time. Anyone help me figure out what am I wrong? I appreciate any help and thank you for any replies.

here's what i did

**Example form (form-edit-account.php)**

```
form name="Form" class="mts-edit-account" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" <?php add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag', 'action_woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' );?> > 
  <!-- Fist & Last Name Field -->
  <div class="row name_surname">
    <div class="form-row">
      <label class="t3" for="account_first_name">Nome *</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo nome" class="field-settings" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label class="t3" for="account_last_name">Cognome *</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo cognome" class="field-settings" name="account_last_name" id="account_last_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->last_name ); ?>" />
    </div> 

    <!-- Save Settings -->
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0px!important;">
      <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce' ); ?>
      <button type="submit" class="edit-account-button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Salva modifiche', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Js File**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
    $('.mts-edit-account').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    //Ajax Handling Error
        var $form = $(this);
        $.post(
      $form.attr('action'), 
      $form.serialize(), 
      function(data) {
        $('.newdiv').html(response);
          }, 'json'
    );

    //Ajax Save settings
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: $(".mts-edit-account").serialize(),
      beforeSend: function() {
        $(".container_loader").show(); 
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $(".container_loader").hide();
        //$('.newdiv').html(data);
      }
    });

    });

});
```

**functions.php** - Updated
`wc_add_notice("Field Name Required", "notice");` and `$response = wc_print_notices( true );` They allow you to view the message, but then the woocommerce success default message is also displayed, so two messages are displayed and not just one.

```
add_action(  'woocommerce_save_account_details_errors', array( &$user, 'save_account_details' ),  10, 1);
add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_account_details', 'save_account_details' );
function save_account_details( &$user ) {
  if (isset( $_POST['account_first_name'] ) == '') {
    wc_add_notice("<b>Name</b> is required field", "error");
    $response = wc_print_notices(true);
  } else if (isset($_POST['account_first_name']) ) {  
    wc_add_notice("Test Message", "success");
    $response = wc_print_notices(true);
  }
  echo json_encode($response);
  exit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wc_add_notice()` adds the notice in session in order to be printed after the reload.

in your case you need to use the printing function `wc_print_notices()`

It should be like that.

```
wc_add_notice("Field Name Required", "notice");
$response = wc_print_notices( true );
```

also, You are using `'wp_ajax_nopriv'`  that means any non logged-in user can send that request and change the settings. you need to remove that.

to print a single notice.

```
ob_start();
wc_print_notice( 'Field Name Required', 'error' );
$response = ob_get_clean();
```

You can browse the full notices functions here

https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-notice-functions.html#source-view.184

Comment: Thank you, it's working, I really appreciate it. However, I still have some small doubts: the `true` value inside `wc_print_notices` returns the text with tags and various `\n \t \t \t`, if instead set to false I display the message correctly with div and style, however beyond to the message I also find the null text, what does it depend on?

Also if I save several times I will have multiple messages displayed at the same time, while I would like the previous message to disappear and the next one is displayed. How can this?

Comment: I just found out that I get two types of messages, the original one from woocommerce, and the one added by me with wc_add_notice. Could you guide me on how to receive only one message?

Comment: in order to get a single notice, you can use wc_print_notice(). I will update the answer